FCM send notification to array of tokens NodeJs
I'm currently using fcm method as below:
Admin.messaging().send(payload)

and my payload is:


{
  name: 'Name notifica',
  notification: { title: 'Titolo', body: 'Body' },
  token: 'token1'
} 



But i would like to send notification to an array of push_tokens
I saw that i can use registration_ids: [] instead of token: ''
But it seems like its deprecated and FCM only accepts token / topics / condition
Any idea how can i do this?

You seem to be using the Admin SDK for Node.js, which has a sendEach method that you can pass an array of messages to.
There is also an example of this in the Firebase documentation on sending a batch of messages. As shown in a box at the top of that documentation section too, the current v1 FCM API does not have a dedicated endpoint for batch sending, so the Admin SDK actually calls the send end point for each individual message.
